# How can I avoid the extra level of list nesting when storing lists in an array in R?

Tags: arrays, r, list

I am trying to store some structures (represented as lists) into a multidimensional array layout. Here is an example, first we return a list of such structures from some computation:

```
set.seed(2017)
fooL <- lapply(1:8, function(i) { foo <- list(barV=runif(sample(5,1)), name=paste(letters[sample(26,3)], collapse='')) })
```

if we inspect this with `str` we see each of these is a list with names `barV` which is a `numeric` vector and `name` which is a character vector

next I want to store these in a multidimensional array, I do the following for that:

```
fooA <- array(fooL, dim=c(2,2,2))
```

but now if I inspect an element of this array (say with `str(fooA[1,1,1])`) I see it is now a list of length one whose first element is the foo, instead of simply the foo. Is there a way to avoid this extra level of "indirection" that gets created here? I.e. i would have expected just as I'm able to say `fooL[[1]]$name` to be able to do `fooA[1,1,1]$name`, instead I have to say `fooA[1,1,1][[1]]$name`. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[[`: `fooA[[1, 1, 1]]$name`.